# Entity Extraction from Natural Language question

Tags: python, nlp, chatbot, spacy, nlp-question-answering

I am trying to build a **Database Q/A Chatbot** (or specifically a *[Natural Language Interface to Database](https://jonaschapuis.com/2017/12/natural-language-interfaces-to-databases-nlidb/#Definition)* if you will!). And I am having trouble extracting the **entities/slots** from the *Natural Language Query*.

Take this example, I have a table

| Interns | Branch | Birthday | Salary($/H) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | Mechanical Engineering | 2000-01-20 | 25 |
| B | IT Engineering | 1999-05-09 | 45 |
| A | Electrical Engineering | 2000-01-20 | 35 |
| C | Mechanical Engineering | 2002-09-13 | 35 |

**Example questions** that user may ask from this table,

- `What is the total salary for intern A?`  - *Desired Entities:* {**Interns**: A}
- `Tell me the aggregate salary for A, B and C.`  - *Desired Entities:* {**Interns**: [A,B,C]} #Notice how column name isn't mentioned
- `Which Interns are persuing Mechanical Engineering Branch?` - *Desired Entities:* {**Branch**: Mechanical Engineering}

### Question:

**How to identify these Entities/Slots?**

- [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39622258/13190386) to a similar question suggests using ***Rule-based recognizers***. But I couldn't find how to build them.

---

#### Things I have tried:

1. Creating a custom **Named Entity Recognition** model using **Spacy** to Identify the *Interns* and *Branch names*. This model was successfully able to identify **values** that were given in the **Training Data** but was **failing** to identify **new values**.
2. **Rules based on Part Of Speech Tagging:** This approach was kinda successful but wasn't **generic**. This means it may not work if the same sentence is spoken in another way.

Comment: Have you tried a [Table question answering model](https://huggingface.co/google/tapas-base-finetuned-wtq) from Huggingface?

Comment: Yes. But unfortunately, it fails to answer the question due to the Large table size (~10000 x ~40).